# Realtek RTL8723BE Network Card not working on Chromium OS

Tags: wifi, gentoo, chrome-os, realtek, chromium-os

I use the Lenovo ThinkPad E550 with Realtek rtl8723be network card and the wifi works perfectly on Windows8.1 or Ubuntu 15.04 .

Now , i run Chromium OS build by [ArnoldTheBat](http://arnoldthebat.co.uk/wordpress/chromium-os/) on it .

The build-weekly-Camd64 working perfectly , but only wifi is not working .

I can't find the rtl8723be module when i type "lsmod" on Chromium OS .

I need the driver for rtl8723be but i don't know how to compile the module .

I googled about my network card using Chromium OS , but nothing solved my problem .

I try to copy the "/lib/firmware/rtlwifi/*rtl8723*.bin" on Ubuntu 15.04 to Chromium OS but has hardly changed .

Chromium OS's kernel version is 3.14.0 .

What should i do ? Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `modprobe rtl8723be`. If it doesn't work, then post result of the following command: `modprobe --dry-run -v rtl8723be`. Run both commands as root.

Comment: When i type these two commands , i get 'modprobe : FATAL: Module rtl8723be not found.'