# Wifi not working and interface not listed

Tags: wifi, network-interface, ifconfig, chromium-os

I installed Chromium OS on a USB stick, and can't get wifi to work. It looks like the interface is missing. Here is the output of some commands:

```
localhost / # ifconfig -a
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1186  bytes 87324 (85.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1186  bytes 87324 (85.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
localhost / # rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
localhost / # lspci -k
....
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2231
...
```

I am fairly new to Linux commands and have no idea what to do next. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**
This might work: https://askubuntu.com/a/593015/399729, however, the `make` command doesn't exist.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214626/realtek-rtl8723be-network-card-not-working-on-chromium-os